# Drawing a line perpendicular to a line on a plane whose normal is known

Tags: algorithm, unity-game-engine, geometry

I have two vector(Vector3) positions of a line on a plane whose normal vector is known .What I am trying to do is draw a line perpendicular to this line on the same plane. 
Suppose end1 and end2 are two vectors representing the ends of the original line
What I am trying right now :

```
                    var line1 = end1 + ( (end2-end1)* 1 );
                    var rotatedLine = Quaternion.AngleAxis( 90, anchor.transform.rotation*Vector3.up ) * end1;
                    //Debug.DrawLine(end2, rotatedLine, Color.blue);
                    var newLine1 = Instantiate(line );
                    LineRenderer lr2 = newLine1.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
                    lr2.SetPosition(0,end1);
                    lr2.SetPosition(1,rotatedLine);
```

where **anchor.transform.rotation*Vector3.up** represents the normal of the plane.
However this does not produce the required results

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use Cross product to calculate perpendicular line:

if N is the plane normal, direction of perpendicular line is:

```
Vector3 dir = Vector3.Cross( N, ( end2 - end1 ).normalized );
```

and the line is defined by:

```
lr2.SetPosition( 0, end1 );
lr2.SetPosition( 1, end1 + dir );
```

(use Cross( ( end2 - end1 ).normalized, N ); for the opposite direction.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer ,setting second position as  "end1+ dir" was where I was going wrong